# Docker mysql: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, mariadb

I edited the question to specify that it's an nodeapp writing with an ts ORM and i'am trying to mount the image to put it in Docker hub.

I'am trying to connect to mysql for creating an database using containers and i can't get to mysql, i have build my app using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM      ubuntu:20.04

RUN       apt-get update 
RUN       apt-get install -y mariadb-server
EXPOSE    3306

FROM      node

WORKDIR   /node/app

COPY      package*.json package-lock*.json 
COPY      . .
RUN       npm install 
RUN       npm install -g typescript
```

Then i run it on Docker desktop and then i get to my CLI where i got this message when i run:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

or when i run

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root  -p

Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
```

That's what i get when i run

```
docker ps -a
```

> 

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
> af1efcf9967e   tazbiopooltech/nodeapp:1.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes             beautiful_hellman
```

Comment: What is the single command this container runs?  You don't show a `CMD` in your Dockerfile.  Typically with a Node-based application that needs to connect to a database, you'd run a separate container based on the unmodified `mysql` image, maybe using Docker Compose to launch that and your application together.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use an [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) for mariadb?

Comment: Well it's true and i tried to do it that way but when i was running my container in the cli returned 'mysql not found' so i tried this way and found this error that i really don't understand so i'am trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: and i don't need a CMD on that because it's an orm app that uses typescript

Answer (score 0):

So i find the problem, i changed for the official mariadb image from docker hub and i mounted the docker-compose.yml this way, hope this helps someone.

```
version: '3'
networks:
    app-tier:
        driver: bridge

services:
    db:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        expose:
            - "3307"
        ports:
            - "3307:3307"
        networks:
            - app-tier
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: testdocker
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test   
        volumes:
            - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    web:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: bash -c 'until !</dev/tcp/db/3307; do sleep 1; done; npm run build'   
        container_name: nodeapp-docker
        ports:
           - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
           - mariadb
        networks:
            - app-tier
```

and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM      node:17-alpine3.12

LABEL     Tarek ZEMMOURI

RUN       apk add --no-cache bash
WORKDIR   /app       
COPY      package*.json package-lock*.json
COPY      . .

RUN       npm install 

EXPOSE    3000

CMD ["npm", "build"]
```